# SQL number Wildcard issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add a wildcard to my date select query so i only pull the day not time. I.e. 2021-03-11 17:54:30.123. I thought a number could be substituted for a #.

```
select AID, LocalCoAltIn,LocalCoAltOut,EventTime
from EXCDS.dbo.WKS_LOG_VIEW
where EventTime like '2021-03-11 ##:##:##:###';
```

My query is returning no values even though they are in the table. Thanks.

Comment: `#` isn't a wildcard, a quick read of the documentation on `LIKE` will tell you that, but why are you not storing your dates as a date and time data type? Fixing the design and then using proper date logic is the *real* solution here.

Comment: It's not my database so the column for the time and date is event time. I have no control over the tables and  types used.

Answer (score 2):

No!  Don't use strings!  One method is to convert to a date:

```
select AID, LocalCoAltIn,LocalCoAltOut,EventTime
from EXCDS.dbo.WKS_LOG_VIEW
where convert(date, EventTime) = '2021-03-11';
```

Another method is to use a range:

```
where EventTime >= '2021-03-11' and
      EventTime < '2021-03-12'
```

Comment: I recommend the range method with the inclusive start and exclusive end date. Unlike the `CONVERT` method,  this can leverage an index on EventTime (if one exists) to efficiently execute the query.

Comment: The range method does exactly what I need. Thanks very much guys.

Comment: Not going to lie I'm very new to all this. There is alot to learn and I'm having to learn very fast. SQL is not part of my day job just something on the side.

Comment: Not sure why the OP has un-accepted this answer; this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `LIKE` operator in most flavors of SQL only support `_` and `*` wildcards (matching any one single, or multiple characters).  Gordon has given you a better approach, but if you wanted to fix your current query on SQL Server you could try:

```sql
SELECT AID, LocalCoAltIn, LocalCoAltOut, EventTime
FROM EXCDS.dbo.WKS_LOG_VIEW
WHERE EventTime LIKE '2021-03-11 [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

SQL Server extended the `LIKE` operator to accept a few extra things, such as character classes.  Here `[0-9]` inside `LIKE` would match any single digit.

Comment: . . I don't mean to sound like I'm scolding you.  But providing an answer that unnecessarily implicitly converts date/time columns to a string . . . well, I know you know better than that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff LOL...I think Dan Guzman already did enough of that.  I was only giving a literal answer, which actually is possible in SQL Server.  I did cite your answer as being the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that `like` operator would work for date as you want, but you still have few options.
Use `DATEPART` function to retrieve year\month\etc and compare it with exact value that you need

`select AID, LocalCoAltIn,LocalCoAltOut,EventTime  from EXCDS.dbo.WKS_LOG_VIEW where DATEPART(year,EventTime) = 2021 AND DATEPART(month,EventTime) = 3 AND DATEPART(day,EventTime = 11);`

Or use Gordon Linoff suggestion if you dont care about exact date part and only need to compare entire date without time

Comment: The range method is the only advisable solution, the use of `datepart` is not sargable and will force sql server to scan the index or table.